# If else check in following code using javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code i am adding events in `ev[]` array by using `ev.push()` function like

```
ev.push({title: v.Message,start:v.StartDate,end:v.EndDate,id: v.EventsCalendarID})
```

and now i want to add a condition in which i want to check Isapproved==true or false and if its true i can add `textColor: 'black'` in `ev.push()` or `textColor: 'red'` if `Isapproved== false.`   How can i perform this check?

```
var events = [
      {
        "EventsCalendarID": 21,
        "AdminUserName": "ManjitSingh",
        "StartDate": "2014-08-27 12:00 AM",
        "EndDate": "8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM",
        "Timezone": "Europe/London",
        "Message": "mabkja",
        "IsApproved": false,
        "UserID": "70348398-9b8e-48a2-bbfc-c2474146d5d5",
        "User": null
      },
      {
        "EventsCalendarID": 22,
        "AdminUserName": "ManjitSingh",
        "StartDate": "2014-08-29 12:00 AM",
        "EndDate": "8/29/2014 1:00:00 AM",
        "Timezone": "Europe/London",
        "Message": "ffd",
        "IsApproved": true,
        "UserID": "70348398-9b8e-48a2-bbfc-c2474146d5d5",
        "User": null
      }
    ];

function success(events) {
  var ev = [];
  $.each(events, function (i, v) {
    ev.push({
      title: v.Message,
      start:v.StartDate,
      end:v.EndDate,
      id: v.EventsCalendarID
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Add `textColor: (v.isApproved?'black':'red')`

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
function success(events) {
  var ev = [];
  $.each(events, function (i, v) {
    ev.push({
      title: v.Message,
      start:v.StartDate,
      end:v.EndDate,
      id: v.EventsCalendarID,
      textColor: v.IsApproved ? 'black' : 'red'
    });
  });
}
```

Note If above condition is not worked than please try with the below

```
 textColor: v.IsApproved == true ? 'black' : 'red'
 textColor: v.IsApproved === true ? 'black' : 'red'
 textColor: v.IsApproved == 'true' ? 'black' : 'red'
```

Let me know if i am not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator `? :`

```
ev.push({
    title:     v.Message,
    start:     v.StartDate,
    end:       v.EndDate,
    id:        v.EventsCalendarID,
    textColor: v.IsApproved === true ? 'black' : 'red'
});
```

Comment: There is no need in comparing `v.IsApproved` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ev.push({textColor: (Isapproved?'black':'red')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness of the answers, you could of course do something like this too:

```
$.each(events, function (i, v) {
    var color;
    if (v.IsApproved) {
        color = 'black';
    else {
        color = 'red';
    }
    ev.push({
        title: v.Message,
        start: v.StartDate,
        end: v.EndDate,
        id: v.EventsCalendarID,
        textColor: color
    });
});
```

But it's definitely better to go with the ternary operation using `? :`. Though in some cases, if the condition using this ternary operation would be too complicated, it might be better to go with the solution I stated above just for better code readability.